# Как в переменную поместить символ арифметической операции

Tags: php

Условия задачи.
Функция, принимающая два параметра - массив чисел и строку, обозначающее арифметическое действие, которое нужно выполнить со всеми элементами массива. Функция должная выводить результат на экран.

Как переменную $math заставить работать как символ арифметического действия? При выводе на экран выводиться строка 1*1 и т.д.

```
$numbers = array(1,2,3,4,5);
$math = "*";

function square($numbers, $math){
    for ($i = 0; $i < count($numbers); $i++){
        echo $numbers[$i] . $math . $numbers[$i]."<br>";
    }
}
square($numbers, $math);
```

Всё ж нужно было просто сделать арифметическую операцию со всеми элементами массива. То есть если массив 1,2,3 и строка + то результат 1+2+3=6

Решил вот таким способом. Правда на других форумах за eval на меня ругаются. Почему его не желательно использовать?

```
    function items($numbers, $math) {
    $result = $numbers[0];
    if (in_array($math, array('*', '+', '/', '-', '%'))) {
        for ($i = 1; $i < count($numbers); $i++) {
            eval('$result = '.$result.$math.$numbers[$i].';');
        }
        echo implode($math, $numbers).'='.$result.'<br/>';
    } else {
        echo $math . ' - неизвестный оператор<br/>';
    }
}
```

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Можно использовать [eval](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.eval.php). Сейчас нет возможности набросать и проверить код. По ссылке есть примеры.

Comment: Вот так решил эту задачу

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ab1618313aa72994206688515f9c0dbee6e98cc4

Comment: фактически тут будет `$result = eval(implode('+', [1,2,3]))`, но задача  тут не на eval, а как в комменте примерно решено. правда сложновато там, вроде

Comment: решил вот таким способом всё ж. Как-то красивее смотрится.
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/fd6462585b6e646ce643611d34d66597a1b36914